# BeautifulSoup only finding partial href from request response

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm looking to extract the href of an element from Amazon's proceed to checkout button. I'm only a beginner so apologies If it's a silly question!

The html is:

```
<a id="hlb-ptc-btn-native" href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/cart/view.html/ref=lh_co?ie=UTF8&amp;proceedToCheckout.x=129&amp;cartInitiateId=1620062291588&amp;hasWorkingJavascript=1" class="a-button-text a-text-center" role="button">
      Proceed to checkout
    </a>
```

My code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(add_ToCart.text, 'html.parser')
href_parent = soup.find('a', attrs={'id':'hlb-ptc-btn-native','class':'a-button-text a-text-center','role':'button'})
href = href_parent.attrs['href']
print(href)
```

However this outputs only part of the href, but I'm interested in the part which contains the cartInitiateId.

```
<Response [200]>
/gp/cart/view.html/ref=lh_co_dup?ie=UTF8&proceedToCheckout.x=129
```

Thank you in advance!

***EDIT:***

Request code:

```
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36',
    'cookie': 'xxx'
}

data = {
  'session-id': 'xxx',
  'ASIN': 'B07ZG7JJNM',
  'quantity': '1',
}

add_ToCart = requests.post('https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/handle-buy-box/ref=dp_start-bbf_1_glance', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Product Url if it matters: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07ZG7JJNM

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the URL and full code you have tried

Comment: What is the expected result value?

Comment: @QHarr I want to grab the cartInitiateId

Comment: Does its value change each time? Can you provide an example full url indicating the cartInitiateId part?

Comment: @QHarr `href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/cart/view.html/ref=lh_co?ie=UTF8&amp;proceedToCheckout.x=129&amp;cartInitiateId=1620066513428"`

Comment: The value does appear to change

Comment: It is present in the response you get back?  `'cartInitiateId=' in add_ToCart.text`